# java language syntax

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android apps in Java of Eclipse. I'm not very familiar with the java syntax. I encounter this error.

```
 The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){},
 Class<NoteEditor> ) is undefined
```

Below is the code

```
ListView lv = getListView();

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditor.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

NoteEditor is extends Activity of Android. The above code is correct because I write it in another place it's no error.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditor.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //newGame();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the code isn't correct, which is why you're getting a compiler error. **this** doesn't refer to what you think it does there; it's referring to the anonymous class you're instatiating.

Comment: change like this Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NoteEditor.class);

Comment: post your whole activity code.

Comment: write this,  Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, NoteEditor.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context used in your code is wrong, as you're using the anonymous inner class's `this`. What you should be using is the Activity's context, like so:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, NoteEditor.class);
```

The first parameter indicates the calling class's context. So you can use the Activity's `this` or `getBaseContext()`

```
public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

Comment: But it show "No enclosing instance of the type NoteEditor is accessible in scope". What's the problem?

Comment: "public class Category extends ListActivity"

Answer (score 1):

Here in your code `this` refers to your `new AdapterView class not a activity`,

and for Intent constructor you have to pass a reference of your current activity or application's base context,

replace your code,

```
ListView lv = getListView();

 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NoteEditor.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }

  });
```

**EDIT:** also you can write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(<your current activity name>.this, NoteEditor.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `this` applies to the anonymous inner class rather than your `Context` subclass instance. In general, you'd write `YourEnclosingClassName.this` to get to that. In your case, you need `NodeEditor.this`.